# is there a way to use 960 and compass with sproutcore?

Tags: sproutcore, 960.gs, compass-sass

Is there a way to do this? I know Compass can be used in sproutcore, but i also want to use the 960 compass plugin. I tried dong import "960/grid" in my app.css but it keeps throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a way it works but I'm not sure if there is a cleaner solution. I just setup a test-project with sproutcore 1.6 and handlebar templates

```
 # sc-init MyTest --template
```

and added an additional "test_960.scss" file in *apps/MyTest/resources/stylesheets* with the following content

```
 @import "960/grid";

 $ninesixty_columns: 16;

 #wrapper {
      @include grid_container;
      background-color: red;
 }
```

However, this does not work since sc-server isn't able to detect the 960 compass plugin. You can easily spot this if you are running sc-server with the **-v** flag to get the debug output. You'll find an exception like this

```
 Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: 960/grid.
 Load paths:
      /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/compass 0.11.3/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
      /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/compass-0.11.3/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
      Compass::SpriteImporter
      [...]
```

The problem is, that the 960 compass plugin isn't installed within *gems/compass 0.11.3/frameworks* but in *gems/compass-960-plugin-0.10.3*. What you can do so, is create a symlink into the framework directory, like that

```
 # cd gems/compass 0.11.3/frameworks
 # ln -s ../../compass-960-plugin-0.10.3 960
```

Stop and restart sc-server and the above example will run now.

I don't know if this has any bad implications on other compass based applications. As said, it works for sproutcore but I had not the time to test it further. This also works with other plugins. Moreover, I did not test if this does also compile correctly when you build your final application.